# Simple way to embed locally-hosted video using HTML, Javascript, or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, embed

I need to put a video in a webpage such that when the page opens, the video will be visible and start playing when the user clicks it. The video file is in .wmv format and stored on the same server that hosts the webpage. I read in some places that it's not easy to get embedded video to work across all browsers, so I'm looking for the simplest way to accomplish that, be it HTML, Javascript, or jQuery. I'd rather not convert the video file or store multiple copies of it if there is a way to not have to do that.

Comment: please change the HTML tag to HTML5 in your question's tag

Comment: Fact is, the easiest way to get video on a webpage these days is to let YouTube or Vimeo host it, because they'll do all the format conversion for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sébastien Renauld and Blazemonger said it.

You can't stream your wmv (windows media video) video across the web reliably because many browsers won't support it.

As Blazemonger said, uploading to YouTube or another video hosting site will take of this for you. They will also provide an embedded url for you which can be sent to all your friends.

Otherwise, as Sébastien Renauld pointed out, you'll need to convert the video into an h.264 .mp4 video AND another format like .ogv or .webM. mp4 is supported by most browsers but not FireFox, which is why you need a second format. Both .ogv and .webM are supported by FireFox.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert your video at least once due to WMV being a proprietary format (that, and as far as I know, the only way to play a WMV is through Windows Media Player activeX add-ins), which, sadly, means multiple copies if you want to deal with all navigators.

Your tool of choice in this is something like jwplayer (http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/). MP4 works on some, while WEBM works on others, and thankfully, flash can read MP4.